# Why "plugin runtime aborted" appears when using some RTL plugin like as Arabic & RTL support or RTL PLZ?

Tags: right-to-left, figma

I am using two RTL plugins in Figma; [Arabic & RTL Support](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/732290356467065314/Arabic-%26-RTL-Support) and [RTL PLZ](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/742121299910255177/RTL-PLZ).
After a lot of RTL texts which are managed by these plugins I have seen a message that says "Plugin runtime aborted" and I could not write new RTL texts or edit them with these plugins.

I check the Figma community to reinstall them but this action rejected and it could not be installed.

I want to know how could I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a temporary bug and it happens when some updates are going in the website or in plugin itself.

These method may work:

1. Uninstall plugin then reinstall it
2. Close all Figma tab in browser (if you work online), clear cache and reopen the file.